# as400 create xml with croatian data

Tags: java, xml, ibm-midrange

I wrote a Java class that runs on as/400 to build an XML file from DB2 data.
I access the DB using native driver (com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver) and the data is in croatian format with special characters like PETROVEÅKI, VRANIÑ and so on.
The DB table where are stored the data filled into the XML file has CCSID 65535.
My first problem is that the driver doesn't accept the default CCSID (65535) of the job, thus in my calling CL program I make a CHGJOB setting CCSID to 870 (should be the croatian).
With this setting I can run succesfully the Java class but the special character are transleted into something else that does not match the original character.
This is the first time I work with those special character and I don't know how to solve it.
Any hint would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the job CCSID is 65535, probably all of the files are too.  Try changing the CCSID of the file to 870 and see if the translation works then.  65535 means 'binary - do not translate'.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions, at last I found the problem. It was due to the display of IFS files (option 5 of IFS files list). Probably that program uses the job CCSID to display charcters inside the file. In my (interactive) job I do this : change ccsid to 870, build the xml file, restore original ccsid (65535). When I look the xml file I see wrong characters. If I change job ccsid to 870 and then display the xml file the characters are all correct.